# How can I mock an `instanceof` test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jestjs, jsdom

In my React code, I listen for a FocusEvent, and perform a check on the type of the element that is being focused:

```
function onBlur(event) {
    if(event.relatedTarget instanceof HTMLInputElement) { /* ... */ }
}
```

This works fine. I just don't seem able to write a proper unit test for it though... I figured I'd be able to call the `onBlur` method as follows:

```
onBlur({ relatedTarget: new HTMLInputElement() });
```

...but unfortunately, that results in an error:

```
TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

I'm using Jest and Enzyme (which I think uses jsdom?), if that matters.

How best to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this you can mock your element:

```
var a = document.createElement('input')
a instanceof HTMLInputElement // returns true
```

If you need to add more behaviour then you can just add it to object a.

Comment: I actually figured out that I could do this (sorry - Rubber Duck Debugging does work) once I realised that `jsdom` was available. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Vincent, please consider accepting an answer if it helped to solve your problems

Comment: But which one? They're both equivalent, and I don't want to contribute to the answering-rat-race by simply accepting the one that was 22s earlier...

Comment: You pick whichever :)

Comment: Lol, this is so funny

Comment: It's just, like, reeaaally important which one I select as the answer, you know? :P

Answer (score 2):

This will evaluate to `true`:

```
document.createElement('input') instanceof HTMLInputElement
```

Comment: I actually figured out that I could do this (sorry - Rubber Duck Debugging does work) once I realised that `jsdom` was available. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One more approach is to change the way to test you input element. You can use `tagName` which should be 'INPUT' string:

```
function onBlur(event) {
    if(event.relatedTarget.tagName === 'INPUT') { /* ... */ }
}

onBlur({ relatedTarget: {tagName: 'INPUT'} });
```

Comment: The problem is that `relatedTarget` can potentially be `null`, which is why I wanted to do the check for it (TypeScript was helpfully complaining :).